# Ограничение количества выводимых записей

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
function SearchContainer({ char, searchTerm, searchTermChanged }) {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Поиск</h1>
      <input
        onChange={e => searchTermChanged(e.target.value)}
        value={searchTerm}
        className="search-input"
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Search"
      />
      <div className="search-tips">
        {char !== ''
          ? char.map((curWords, key) => <p key={key}>{curWords}</p>)
          : char}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default connect(
  store => store,
  actions
)(SearchContainer);
```

Как вывести определенное количество записей? Например ограничить их число 5-ю. На данном этапе выводит всё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть просто воспользоваться методом `slice()`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```
char.slice(0, 5).map((curWords, key) => <p key={key}>{curWords}</p>
```

Comment: Точно, ведь смотрел на slice(), но засомневался, а надо было попробовать. Начал прописывать какие-то условия и зарылся в них совсем. Иногда лучше проще, чем мудрить. Благодарю. Именно то, что надо.

Comment: @COdek удачи!:)